# Dynamodb - remove array element by value not ordinal position

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have the following JSON object in a DynamoDB table - primary sort key is `principle_id`

```json
{
  "info": {
    "key": "a45fa047",
    "secret": "AYADeIbp",
    "groups": [
      "g-0",
      "g-1",
      "g-2",
      "g-3"
    ],
    "is_active": true
  },
  "principle_id": "aaa-0"
}
```

I want to be able to remove specific `groups` elements by there value, i.e. "g-1".

I've am able to do this using the ordinal position i.e. the below successfully removes "g-1".

```java
    Table table = dynamoDB.getTable("my_table");

    UpdateItemSpec updateItemSpec = new UpdateItemSpec()
        .withPrimaryKey("principle_id", "aaa-0")
        .withUpdateExpression("remove info.groups[1]")
        .withReturnValues(ReturnValue.ALL_NEW);

    UpdateItemOutcome outcome = table.updateItem(updateItemSpec);
```

But I'm struggling to find out how to do this via the value.

Any pointers on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell it's not possible using DynamoDB.

The [UpdateItemSpec](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/document/spec/UpdateItemSpec.html#withUpdateExpression-java.lang.String-) indicates the 'withUpdateExpression' method just takes a valid DyanmoDB expression string.

The [UpdateExpressions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html) document just says you need to use a document path reference.

And then the [only way described of getting items in a list using a document path](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.Attributes.html) uses the list position (i.e. info.groups[1]). If you had a map you could specify it by the map key instead in case that was an option.